# Implementing multiple nonlinear regression with custom function in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, machine-learning, regression

I am unable to get Accord.Net to estimate coefficients for a custom function with two independent variables and one output. It simply outputs the same values I gave for my initial coefficient estimates.

A little background: I am trying to use multiple nonlinear regression to estimate the best values for the coefficients in the following function:

`Z = A+1/(1/(X/256*B+3*C)+1/(Y/1024*D+2*E))`

The independent variables are X and Y with Z as the output. I have a best guess for the coefficients that I would like to use to reduce computational requirements:

`A = 20`

`B = 10000`

`C = 50`

`D = 50000`

`E = 60`

I successfully used MatLab's Curve Fitting Toolbox to get a good fit but I need to be able to automate this in C# via Visual Studio since the process will be done many times with different measurements. I found a couple of promising Nuget packages that have some machine learning tools and I ended up on Accord.Net.

```
  double[,] data =
  {
    { 0,    0,    89.05295649 },
    { 128,  0,    123.2124033 },
    { 255,  0,    124.1087122 },
    { 0,    512,  196.9215557 },
    { 128,  512,  4270.278414 },
    { 255,  512,  7149.23716  },
    { 0,    1023, 197.4947063 },
    { 128,  1023, 4672.482543 },
    { 255,  1023, 8360.098631 }
  };

  // Extract inputs and outputs
  double[][] inputs = new double[2][];

  inputs[0] = data.GetColumn(0);
  inputs[1] = data.GetColumn(1);

  double[] outputs = data.GetColumn(2);

  var nls = new NonlinearLeastSquares()
  {

    NumberOfParameters = 5,

    // Initialize to ideal values from A+1/(1/(X/256*B+3*C)+1/(Y/1024*D+2*E))
    StartValues = new[] { 20.0, 10000.0, 50.0, 50000.0, 60.0 },

    Function = (w, x) => w[0] + 1 / (1 / (x[0] / 256 * w[1] + 3 * w[2]) + 1 / (x[1] / 1024 * w[3] + 2 * w[4])),

    // Derivative in respect to the weights:
    Gradient = (w, x, r) =>
    {
      // w.r.t a: A https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff+A%2B1%2F(1%2F(X%2F256*B%2B3*C)%2B1%2F(Y%2F1024*D%2B2*E))+w.r.t.+A
      r[0] = 1;
      // w.r.t b: B https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff+A%2B1%2F(1%2F(X%2F256*B%2B3*C)%2B1%2F(Y%2F1024*D%2B2*E))+w.r.t.+B
      r[1] = x[0] * ((2048 * w[4] + w[3] * x[1]) * (2048 * w[4] + w[3] * x[1])) / (256 * ((3072 * w[2] + 2048 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1]) * (3072 * w[2] + 2048 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1])));
      // w.r.t c: C https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff+A%2B1%2F(1%2F(X%2F256*B%2B3*C)%2B1%2F(Y%2F1024*D%2B2*E))+w.r.t.+C
      r[2] = 3 * ((2048 * w[4] + w[3] * x[1]) * (2048 * w[4] + w[3] * x[1])) / ((3072 * w[2] + 2048 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1]) * (3072 * w[2] + 2048 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1]));
      // w.r.t c: D https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff+A%2B1%2F(1%2F(X%2F256*B%2B3*C)%2B1%2F(Y%2F1024*D%2B2*E))+w.r.t.+D
      r[3] = x[1] * ((768 * w[2] + w[1] * x[0]) * (769 * w[2] + w[1] * x[0])) / 64 * ((3072 * w[2] + 2048 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1]) * (3072 * w[2] + 2048 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1]));
      // w.r.t c: E https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff+A%2B1%2F(1%2F(X%2F256*B%2B3*C)%2B1%2F(Y%2F1024*D%2B2*E))+w.r.t.+E
      r[4] = 32 * ((768 * w[2] + w[1] * x[0]) * (768 * w[2] + w[1] * x[0])) / ((3072 * w[2] + 2048 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1]) * (3072 * w[2] + 2048 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1]));
    },


    Algorithm = new LevenbergMarquardt()
    {
      MaxIterations = 20000,
      Tolerance = 0
    }

  };

  var regression = nls.Learn(inputs, outputs);

  var prediction = regression.Transform(new double[] { 200, 350 });
```

I would expect to see something closer to the following:

`A =  27.85`

`B =  9886.98`

`C =  56.87`

`D =  48581.00`

`E =  48.47`

The output is just giving me the original estimated values even after running through all 20000 iterations. The example on the Accord website shows it for a single independent variable with much simpler gradients so it's hard to say if my problem works with their NonLinearLeastSquares class. Maybe, there's a better solution? I would like to stick with what's available on Nuget since this will have to be maintained on multiple geographically separated systems.

UPDATE:
I changed the squared terms in the gradients to use the Math.Pow method and it at least resulted in changing coefficients. However, it is very inaccurate. I noticed that the B coefficient still doesn't change no matter what I choose for the starting point as if something is wrong with the code I am using for the r[1] gradient. But I can't see anything wrong with it.

```
    Gradient = (w, x, r) =>
    {
      r[0] = 1;
      //(X (2048 E + D Y)^2)/(256 (3072 C + 2048 E + 4 B X + D Y)^2)
      r[1] = x[0] * Math.Pow(2048.0 * w[4] + w[3] * x[1], 2.0) / (256 * Math.Pow(3072 * w[2] + 2048.0 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1], 2.0));
      //(3 (2048 E + D Y)^2)/(3072 C + 2048 E + 4 B X + D Y)^2
      r[2] = 3 * Math.Pow(2048.0 * w[4] + w[3] * x[1], 2.0) / Math.Pow(3072.0 * w[2] + 2048.0 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1], 2.0);
      //((768 C + B X)^2 Y)/(64 (3072 C + 2048 E + 4 B X + D Y)^2)
      r[3] = (Math.Pow(768 * w[2] + w[1] * x[0], 2.0) * x[1]) / (64 * Math.Pow(3072.0 * w[2] + 2048.0 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1], 2.0));
      //(32 (768 C + B X)^2)/(3072 C + 2048 E + 4 B X + D Y)^2
      r[4] = 32 * Math.Pow(768 * w[2] + w[1] * x[0], 2.0) / Math.Pow(3072.0 * w[2] + 2048.0 * w[4] + 4 * w[1] * x[0] + w[3] * x[1], 2.0);
    },
```

`A: 44469.142086254556`

`B: -243110.88545066063`

`C: -303081.17150483071`

`D: 50000`

`E: -23237.027101692031`

Comment: On http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Models_Regression_Fitting_NonlinearLeastSquares.htm, their example shows links to wolframalpha also, their derivatives come to x^2, x, and 1 respectively. But when they put the equations into Gradient they use a^2, b, and 1 respectively. I'm not sure why they differ, but I'm assuming there is something mathematically wrong with your code, not that your equation is too complex for the library. Unfortunately, I'm a C# programmer so I don't understand NonlinearLeastSquares regressions well enough to help.

Comment: @Rhaokiel I agree that was strange. However, their second example on that page shows them using the partial for (a*x)/(b+x) w.r.t a and they put the gradient in the same way I did (based on the output of wolfram). I did notice that for some reason they use -((-x[0]) / (w[1] + x[0])) instead of (x[0]) / (w[1] + x[0]). I'm grasping at straws here but I'll see if adding that leading negative helps at all... No such luck. Still getting the same coefficients that I input.

Comment: Most non-linear solvers return the best parameter values they find, and if the initial starting parameters cannot be improved then those are returned because the software could not find anything better.

Comment: @JamesPhillips, I thought that might be the case so I tried arbitrary initial starting parameters and it returned those as well, despite resulting in a very bad R^2. It's running through all 20000 iterations but it's not changing anything. Gradient issue, perhaps, but I triple checked their formatting based on the partials from wolfram

Comment: I have a test to try: use the Matrix Laboratory (MATLAB) values to all decimal places and verify the same results, there should be few (if any) iterations. Then try with those same values truncated to five decimal places, there should be improvement of those starting values. Finally, try truncating to two decimal places - there should again be improvement.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I tried using the MATLAB estimated parameters to 15 decimal places and, unfortunately, it returned them unchanged after running through all 20000 iterations

Comment: @JamesPhillips same thing with the values truncated down to two decimals

Comment: As I understand your work, the 15 decimal place values should have made very few iterations, so this was a good test to try. Have you made a similar test of a simpler model such as a flat plane equation "z = a * x + b * y + c"? At present I would try making your code match MATLAB in the simple case first, and only then move to your current model.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I tried a simple case with two independent variables and it appeared to function (at least returning coefficients that were changed). I noticed Accord uses Math.Pow in one of their example whereas I was not. I added that and it appears to at least have some affect on the outcome. I am getting changing coefficients but the resulting prediction is very inaccurate. I suspect it has something to do with the gradients. I updated the original question with the change

Comment: I noticed that the only coefficient that doesn't change is B (no matter what value I use for the starting point). If something was wrong with the way it's handling that gradient it would explain why the other coefficients get way off in trying to compensate. I can't find anything wrong with the gradient code, though.

Comment: I have another test you can try, and though it will run slowly it should pinpoint any gradient problem. Calculate each gradient by changing each parameter individually by +/- 0.1 percent and use "parameter_gradient = delta_parameter / delta_y". It will make a lot of calculations, but this is a test.

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find a solution using this library?